# \boxed math expression makes font too large when used in nested fractions or exponents

Tags: math-mode, mathtools, size

Using the `\boxed` environment in mathtools seems to ignore the default size considerations LaTeX makes with nested fractions:

```
\[
\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{\boxed{\frac{1}{2}}}
\]
```

I would like the `\boxed` 1/2 to be the same size as the numerator, instead, the following is produced:

[image]

How can I resolve this, preferably in a general way so that `\boxed` doesn't change affect the font size in any situation?

EDIT: This also happens for exponents, as in the following:

```
\[
e^x, e^{\boxed{x}}
\]
```

[image]

Comment: Try `\[
\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{\boxed{\tfrac{1}{2}}}
\]`

Comment: Thanks - that works for `\frac`, but doesn't fix the other situations in which this happens.

Comment: What situation? Boxed math expression is always in `display` size., so there is no general solution.

Comment: `\boxed` comes from `amsmath` (loaded by `mathtools`, thus not `mathtools` related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a command that takes into consideration the current math style and `\mathpalette` is the right tool.

I also reduced the padding, that seemed too large for the intended application.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\xboxed}[1]{\mathpalette\xboxed@{#1}}
\newcommand{\xboxed@}[2]{{\fboxsep=1.4pt\boxed{#1#2}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{\xboxed{\frac{1}{2}}}\qquad e^x, e^{\xboxed{x}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly!